# How to parse custom text file for analyize

Tags: java, parsing

I'm having a logfile like this:

```
1352711989.822313 SENDING
  SR packet
    SSRC                  3760482201
    NTP timestamp: 1352711989.822293
    RTP timestamp:          30163617
    Packets sent:                 17
    Octets sent:                  85
    RR block 1
      SSRC                2520738017
      Fraction lost:               0
      Packets lost:                0
      Ext. high. seq. nr:      64175
      Jitter:                   2947
      LSR:                1035041236
      DLSR:                   284839
    RR block 2
      SSRC                2158728709
      Fraction lost:              14
      Packets lost:               43
      Ext. high. seq. nr:      54178
      Jitter:                    394
      LSR:                1035176766
      DLSR:                   149303
    RR block 3
      SSRC                 100700967
      Fraction lost:              36
      Packets lost:              120
      Ext. high. seq. nr:      45647
      Jitter:                   2365
      LSR:                1035002733
      DLSR:                   323342
  SDES Chunk:
    SSRC:                 3760482201
```

And I would like to parse every block into an object, So I made some classes in java.
Now is there a way to smoothly go through this text and put everyting in the right var and do that for the whole text file?

So at the end I have a list with objects that contains there information.

Comment: Can you provide an example object created from this data?

Comment: You can iterate over each line of the file with a BufferedReader.  For each line you need to check if it begins with a certain phrase, then make decisions accordingly.  This is the straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like everything here is name value pairs the easiest thing to do would be to iterate over the lines of the file and add each line to a map.  If the name blocks are important (ex. `RR block 2`) you can create a list that you add the current name piece to when you don't have a value, then pop it off once you get to the next piece with the same indentation.